# How to manage firebase by URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, sim800l

Good night.

May someone help me?

I'm trying to upload data throught arduino and SIM800L to firebase, I have seen one tutorial in github but It didn't work for me, I have done a code to upload data to thingspeak db and it works with url using get method, If I put this in the navigator i see the data in thingsepak:
https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=API_KEY&field1=0DATA1&field2=-0DATA2&field3=0DATA3
So in thingspeak I'm going to see in field1:DATA1, field2:-DATA2, field3:DATA3

Is It possible to make the same with firebase?
For example:
https://api.firebaseio.com/update?api_key=API_KEY&field1=0data1&field2=0

Sorry for my english

Kind regards,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database has a [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database) that you can access using any modern HTTP client.

Some of the operations will not work if you are just using a web browser to enter a URL.  If you want something that allows you to write data purely by URL, you will have to build that API yourself.

Comment: Given the mention of `firebaseio.com` I expect OP to be using Realtime Database.

Comment: Hi Frank, yes I'm using Realtime DataBase.
Hi Doug, thanks for your reply I'm reviewing the link and I can see data throught web browser, and now I have some ideas to probe in my code, I'm going to probe tomorrow and I'll tell you